# Split exact sequences.

Tags: exact-sequence

***Edit:*** The setting is some abelian category.

The splitting lemma says that the following conditions are equivalent for a short exact sequence $$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$$

1. The left arrow has a left inverse
2. The right arrow has a right inverse
3. Both the above conditions hold in such a way that $B$ is the biproduct of $A$ and $C$

A short exact sequence is said to split if it satisfies any of the above conditions.
Given a biproduct, the sequence $$0\rightarrow A\overset{\iota _1}{\rightarrow} A\oplus C\overset{\pi _2}{\rightarrow}C\rightarrow 0$$ is always exact, and in fact always split.
Now, Borceux says that the splitting lemma asserts *that all split exact sequences are of this type up to isomorphism*.

But why the "up to isomorphism"? "The" biproduct is not really unique, so it seems that for any split sequence, $B$ is just a "version" of $A\oplus C$. What isomorphism is Borceux talking about? Is he picking a particular "version" of the biproduct and merely saying all the others are isomorphic to it?

Comment: "up to isomorphism" because $B$ is not, set-theoretically, $A \oplus C$.

Comment: @Hoot set-theoretically? I don't follow

Comment: What are $A,B$ and $C$? Modules?  Groups?  Something else?

Comment: Objects in some abelian category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One point to make is that the author isn't simply saying that $B$ is isomorphic to $A\oplus C$.  Rather, he's saying that the two *short exact sequences* are isomorphic (in the category of short exact sequences).  This is a stronger statement.

However, I think your point is correct, that he could simply say "all short exact sequences are of this form", relying on the fact $A\oplus C$ (and the whole sequence containing it) is only *defined* up to isomorphism anyhow.  This relies on taking $A\oplus C$ to be defined by its universal property.  In some familiar abelian categories, though, we might define $A\oplus C$ to consist of pairs $(a,c)$ with $a \in A$ and $c\in C$.  In that case, $A\oplus C$ is defined as a set, and therefore we need to point out that $B$ is not the same *set* as $A\oplus C$, i.e., that it is only isomorphic to it.  (This is the set-theoretic issue which Hoot referred to.)

Comment: Borceux does not mention any category of short exact sequences (and I don't see how he implicitly hints at such a thing) though. At any rate, I'm only concerned with $A\oplus C$ as a universal object. I'm just a bit concerned that you *think* my point is correct, so I'll wait a bit more for someone to tell me for certain :)